# Winforms label bug?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

### Winforms label acts strange after its font is changed more than once from the `Resize` event.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Add a label -with `AutoSize` property set to false- to any container (form, panel,.. etc).
- Change the `BorderStyle` property of it to `FixedSingle` (just to be able to visually track its size).
- Change the `Dock` property to `Fill`.
- In the `Resize` event write some code to change the font of the label twice:

  ```
  Private Sub Label1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Resize
      Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, 14)
      Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, 16)  ' Must be two different fonts (e.g. different font sizes).
  End Sub
  ```
- Now run the application and start changing the size of the label container. Will notice that the label size doesn't change with its container while the `Dock` property is still set to `Fill`!

**P.S.** This only happens when using the `Dock` property (i.e. if `Anchor` property is used instead, the problem disappears).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Does anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I think it is a bad practice to update a font from the resize event. It will cause cascading resizes and recalculations. Sure you don't have another event?

Comment: I think that `Label` has it's own sizing and positioning pattern. It gets the drawing area of the parent and then it measures the string itself, takes the position of the text ( ie. Top-Left ) and then adds a margin.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes. I tested it with a brand new winforms application with no more code/controls.

Comment: The problem is that resizing now causes resizing.

Comment: @m.rogalski, I think what you're talking about occurs only when the `AutoSize` property is set to `True`. Since it's set to false, the label should have no control over its size, let alone that this problem doesn't happen until you change the font more than once (and only from the `Resize` event).

Comment: I think this is more complex than we might first think. If you check the [Font](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/9df809cb5bb5d985.html) property in reference source you might deduce that changing the parent font (this) instead of the label font solves your issue. If you stop change the font and resize, the control remains docked. I have no explanation now, but i'm just stating my observation.

Comment: @user3185569, changing the parent font instead of the label produces the same result (undocked label). I don't understand the second part of your comment "If you stop change the font and resize..."

Comment: @PatrickHofman, are you sure that changing the font property **for a non-autosized label** changes its size? And even if that's true, why does the label get undocked? and why does this only happen if called from the `Resize` event and only if called more than once?

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Well i Just replaced your two lines with `this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 16);` (C#) .. And the label remains docked when I resize the form. Note that his is tested under .NET 4.6

Comment: Well, I just tested that while the parent is a form and yes the label remains docked but the form keeps fighting resizing. **While** if the parent is not a form (e.g. docked panel) the same behavior mentioned in the question stays.

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN This is because font change invokes resize also.. so you need to unsubscribe before that and resubscribe again.. Check this: `label1.Resize -= label1_Resize; this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.Size + 1); label1.Resize += label1_Resize;` (C#.. you need to convert to VB).. This makes gradual smooth resizing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130084/discussion-between-genius-brain-and-user3185569).

Comment: Yeah, you could call this a bug, some evidence [in the Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,1001) that the Microsoft programmer struggled with it.  It has a fairly stupid workaround, add a constructor to your form if you don't have one yet (Sub New) and turn on the right anchor on the label after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: The problem is not limited to `Font` property. You can see changing `Text` and `Padding` properties also cause the problem. The root cause is changing these properties cause calling the internal `AdjustSize` which changed the size. In this method, the author forgot to check `Dock` property, while they checked for `Anchor`.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes yes yes! The damn method `AdjustSize` was it. Thank you, I totally got it now. Also RezaAghaei, I agree with you. Thank you for investigating this and providing more details :)